# Question on Linear Dependence and Independence

Tags: linear-algebra

Here's a question from Curtis's Linear Algebra: An Introductory Approach:

> Show that a set of vectors, which contains the set of linearly
>   dependent vectors, is linearly dependent. What is the analogous
>   statement about linearly independent vectors?

Here's my attempt:

Let $S$ be a finite set of vectors which contain $W=\{ w_1 , w_2 , \ldots, w_n \}$, a set of linearly dependent vectors. Then, by definition of linearly dependent vectors,

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_{i} w_{i}=0$$

for some $\lambda_1 , \ldots , \lambda_n  \in \mathbb{F}$ such that some $\lambda_i$ are nonzero. Further, we can write

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_{i} w_{i} + \sum_{v \in (S\setminus W) } 0\cdot v =0$$

This shows $S$ is linearly dependent.

The analogous statement about linearly independent vectors would be that a set of vectors, which contains the set of linearly independent vectors is linearly independent which is false since $\{ (1,1) , (2,1), (1,2) \}$ is linearly dependent for $-3(1,1)+ (2,1)+(1,2)=0$ however the set $\{ (1,1) , (2,1) \}$ is linearly independent.

Is my proof and argument okay?

Comment: The proof is correct. The analogous statement ought to be valid. Just reverse the inclusion.

Comment: @Berci that seems right.